# Wave equation on a compact Riemannian surface without boundary: no mass conservation?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Consider a compact, smooth Riemmanian surface $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ without boundary.

I would like to solve the wave equation:

$$u_{tt} + \Delta_{\mathcal{S}} u = 0$$

under the conditions:

$$u(0,x) = \delta_y(x)\\ u_t(0,x) = 0,$$

where $\Delta_{\mathcal{S}}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $\mathcal{S}$.

If I am not mistaken (please let me know if I am), the solution can be explicitly written down in terms of the Laplace-Beltrami eigenfuctions $\{\phi_k\}_{k\geq 1}$, which form a basis of $L^2(\mathcal{S})$, and the corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_k$:

$$u(t,x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos(\sqrt{\lambda_k}t) \phi_k(y) \phi_k(x)$$

Now, what surprises me, is that "mass" is not conserved in the sense that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{\mathcal{S}} u(x,t) dx = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} -\sqrt{\lambda_k}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_k}t) \phi_k(y) \int_{\mathcal{S}}\phi_k(x) dx$$

So "mass" changes over time depending on the $\lambda_k$ and thus on the geometry of the surface.

**Question**: Is there an intuitive explanation of why $\int_{\mathcal{S}} u(x,t) dx$ is not a conserved quantity?

Comment: The mass would be a conserved property for the heat equation. Why should it be a conversed property for the wave equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For generic initial data, the mass is *never* a conserved quantity for wave equations (except sometimes in 1+1 dimensions). Not even over Euclidean space. (In $\mathbb{R}^3$ for spherically symmetric, out-going initial data you can check explicitly that the mass grows at a rate that is about linearly in time.)

So there is absolutely no reason why you should expect that mass is conserved for general evolution on a Riemannian manifold.

(Are you perhaps thinking of energy? (Or the mass in the $L^2$ sense?) That would be the natural conserved quantity for the wave equation on Euclidean space, and indeed, they are conserved also in the case you replace the space by a Riemannian manifold.)

---

For the specific case you are looking at, where the initial data has $u_t(0,x) = 0$, indeed you have conservation of total integral. And you've also proven it already in your question: eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator with non-zero eigenvalues have mean zero (integrate both sides of $-\triangle \phi_k = \lambda_k \phi_k$).

Comment: By "energy", do you mean the following quantity:

$$E(u)=\left\lVert \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \right\rVert_{L^2_x}^2 + \lVert \nabla u\rVert_{L^2_x}^2 ?$$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: yes.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this statement - if M is a compact, boundaryless Riemannian manifold, then the wave equation (with zero initial data) does conserve integrals wrt the Riemannian volume. This is because the time-$s$ solution operator $cos(s\sqrt{-\Delta})$ is self-adjoint, and leaves the constant function invariant. By finite propagation speed, this should extend to any complete Riemannian manifold, at least when the initial data has compact support (see also Taylor's PDE I book, Section 6, eq. 2.36)  Or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @NathanaelSchilling: bad phrasing on my part. The answer as it stood was wrong. Let me edit my answer to be clearer.

Comment: @NathanaelSchilling: to be more clear: I was answering the wrong question (didn't read the OP closely enough). For general initial data, the wave equation does not conserve the mass. Of course as you pointed out for data with vanishing initial velocity the mass is conserved. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Another minor comment: I think that for the general wave equation, mass should grow *exactly* linearly - to see this, take a Fourier-Transform, and note that the 0-th Fourier-coefficient satisfies the ODE c'' = 0 with c(0) and c'(0) given by the 0th Fourier-coefficients of the initial value and velocity respectively. So if the initial velocity has integral 0, then in fact mass is also conserved.  

The same reasoning works on any compact Riemannian manifold. I can't seem to find a reference for any of this, so if there is a mistake in my reasoning let me know.

Comment: @NathanaelSchilling: yes, up to the usual quibble about whether $ax+b$ is a linear function. :-)

Comment: yes, of course :)